# Using django model as argument for pytest parametrization

Tags: python, django, django-models, pytest

I'm trying to test if users of different business groups are allowed to make an action in a webapp using parametrization features of pytest but I can't get access to fixtures values inside parametrize.

First approach:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mike_user():
    user = User(username="mike", email="mike@test.com",)
    user.set_password("test")
    user.save()
    return user


@pytest.fixture
def mike_business_group(mike_user):
    bg = BusinessGroup.objects.create(
        name="Mike Business Group", user=mike_user
    )
    bg.save()
    return bg.pk


@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "resource, user, serialized_data, success",
    [
        (
            "/business/",
            mike_user,
            {
                "name": "New business",
                "description": "Hi Stackoverflow",
                "group": mike_business_group,
            },
            True,
        ),
    ],
)
def test_create_model_with_related_owner(
    apiclient, user, resource, serialized_data, success
):
    apiclient.force_authenticate(user=user)
    response = apiclient.post(resource, data=serialized_data)
    assert (
        response.status_code == 201
    ) is success
```

Seeing lazy_fixture package I tried the following but it only success resolving `mike_user` having the following dictionary value for the second resolution:

```
{'name': 'Marina L4bs', 'description': 'Happy BioHacking', 'group': <LazyFixture "mike_business_group">}
```

Second approach:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "resource, user, serialized_data, success",
    [
        (
            "/business/",
            pytest.lazy_fixture("mike_user"),
            {
                "name": "Marina L4bs",
                "description": "Happy BioHacking",
                "group": pytest.lazy_fixture('mike_business_group'),
            },
            True,
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a third approach I created a fixture for the second argument of the parametrization instead of trying to lazy load the value of the business_group but I think that even if it works, it does'nt feel like the proper way and should exist a better way.

```
@pytest.fixture
def business_creation_for_mike_business_group(mike_business_group):
    return {
        "name": "Marina L4bs",
        "description": "Happy BioHacking",
        "group": mike_business_group,
    }

@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "resource, user, serialized_data, success",
    [
        (
            "/business/",
            pytest.lazy_fixture("mike_user"),
            pytest.lazy_fixture("business_creation_for_mike_business_group"),
            True,
        ),
    ],
)
```